# Libre Calc 'B5' shows #NAME? when using OpenPyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl, libreoffice-calc

PROBLEM: Why Libre Calc 'B5' shows "#NAME?" not the amount 110?

I wrote Python using OpenPyxl

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()

cashbook = wb.active

Receipts = wb.create_sheet('Cashbook Receipts')

Receipts['B4'] = 100

Receipts['E4'] = 10

Balance_Sheet = wb.create_sheet('Balance Sheet')

Balance_Sheet['B5'].value = "=$'Cashbook Receipts'.$B$4+$'Cashbook Receipts'.$E$4"

wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

In Libre Calc it shows as below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xkKw.png

What happened? what did I do wrong?

Comment: Your code ist contradict to what you explaine. [Edit] your Question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: I reprhrase the challenge of overcoming #NAME? hope this is clearly explain to anybody

Comment: I can confirm, using **openpyxl: 2.4.1** - **LibreOffice: 5.2.7.2***. Seems a [LibreOffice bug](https://listarchives.libreoffice.org/global/users/msg26785.html)

Comment: Thank you for answer, LIbreOffice Version: 6.0.6.2. How I find out what version of openpyxl do I have?  Also I tried to save in xls, " quotation mark have moved after the = equal symobol as it turned into ="$'Cashbook Receipts'.$B$4+$'Cashbook Receipts'.$E$4" .

Comment: `print(openpyxl.__version__)`

Comment: Cell references in formulae are of the form `'sheetname'!$A$1` with the exclamation mark as the separator.

Comment: Yes Charile, I suspect that is the "serious" problem in terms of design flaw in Python Language when using OpenPyxl.  To have ' includedJust, it requires " " (quotation mark) between ' to make it work.  I doubt if there any other solution, perhaps 0x0O22 can work between ' ' whilst assigning it to alance_Sheet['B5'].value.